# How to copy artifact from one local repo to another local repo?

Tags: maven

Let's suppose there two local repos: `~/.m2/repository` and `~/temp/repository`, and there is such a folder`~/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.11`. Can I just copy manually `~/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.11` to `~/temp/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/`?

I want to understand if it will break the second (`~/temp/repository`) repo? By other words, does maven use any indexes, caches etc because of which such manual copying won't work.

Comment: It will probably work for most purposes (maybe not for determining the highest version of something). Generally, I would avoid such hacks. Why are you planning to do this?

Comment: @JFabianMeier I didn't find how to do it using `mvn`.

Comment: Ok, but what is the problem you want to solve? I never had a situation where I wanted to copy from one local repository to another. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @JFabianMeier I work now on one project and according to its spec jars of the project must be stored in the project (internal) maven repo.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I know about maven-resolver, but the problem is with bootstrap jars.

Comment: Then load the jars from MavenCentral or from a company Nexus/Artifactory instead of copying them around.